# Can I drop to be verb in passive voice in these cases? Is it correct, what is the grammatical name of this phenomenon?

Tags: grammar

Entries successfully merged, pull request successfully merged?

Comment: This could do with a little more clarity about what you want to know.

Comment: @KillingTime I wanted to know if it's grammatically correct to drop the **were** in Entries were succesfully merged

Comment: You should always edit additional details into the question rather than answering in comments (since comments can be deleted or moved to chat). That way answerers can see the details in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can. These are instances of reduced passive relative clauses.
Reduced relative clauses are common in English:

> A ***reduced relative clause*** is a relative clause that is *not marked by an explicit relative pronoun or complementizer* such as ***who, which*** or ***that***. A ***participle*** can often be used instead of a relative pronoun and full verb.
> e.g.
>
> - *Bikes* ***that are ridden*** to school must be left in the bicycle racks. (full relative clause)
> - *Bikes* ***ridden*** to school must be left in the bicycle racks. (participial phrase) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause))

Sometimes, as the Wikipedia article shows, reduced relative clauses can be too ambiguous. But your examples do not have that sort of ambiguity. ***Merged*** is the past participle of the verb ***to merge***, which is used in the passive voice.

Thus, instead of saying

> Entries ***that/which were*** successfully *merged*

you can drop the bold part and you get the phrase you suggested:

> Entries successfully *merged*

Comment: Thank you very much